# ASP MVC Controller post same html input name with different values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this input type that needs to be cloned sample html is below.

```
<input type="text"id="person" name="Person" class="person-list" />
<input type="text"id="person" name="Person" class="person-list" />
```

I want to get the values of the two input through MVC. The code below is my current work but it only gets the value of the first input.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmationPage(string Person){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method needs to be

```
public ActionResult ConfirmationPage(string[] Person){ // or IEnumerable<string>
```

However your also creating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes so you should remove those from the inputs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmationPage(string[] Person){

}

<input type="text" name="Person" class="person-list" />
<input type="text"  name="Person" class="person-list" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is fixed. **Stephen Muecke's** answer is absolutely correct. I just want to add one point to that.

You can specify indices of your array elements from your html or view page.

```
<!-- You are specifying that this input should be Person[0] -->
<input type="text" name="Person[0]" class="person-list" />
<input type="text" name="Person[1]" class="person-list" />
```

I know this is just a small point, but some times you can use this.